# Table with Add row option for external users

Tags: commerce

I am trying to build a training website. If the external user is booking a slot for a training class for 10 people he should be able to add 10 people details like the Name, address etc., at checkout. I am thinking to provide the ability to add each attendee details to the table with an "Add row" option dynamically by the external user.

Is this possible? Do we have any modules for this? I checked with datatable module I didn't find this option. Could anyone please suggest me on this.

Example View:[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. We can use Matrix webform component module(https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_matrix_component) to achieve this.